# making observe events reactive in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to make the observe events reactive in shiny? For example, in the application below, when the user clicks on the button, the particular row number should be printed in the console. Here is just a sample application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
number_compare <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:100, 10, rep=TRUE)))


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               uiOutput("rt"),
               DTOutput("example_table"))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  number_compare <- number_compare %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), button = glue::glue(HTML('<button id="button{rn}" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Ask a question</button>')))
  
  output$rt <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Sd","Select",choices = number_compare$X1)
  })
  
  output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
    
    number_compare <- number_compare %>% filter(X1 %in% input$Sd)
    
    datatable(
      number_compare,
      escape = FALSE
      ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
        'function() {
     Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
        drawCallback= JS(
          'function(settings) {
       Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
  })
  
  # observe({
  #   lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  #     id <- paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][x,])
  #     observeEvent(input[[id]], {print(x)})
  #   })
  # })

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to make the observe events reactive in shiny? For example, in the application below, when the user clicks on the button, the particular row number should be printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The following does print the row number in the console.

```
lapply(1:nrow(number_compare), function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][x,])]], {print(x)})
})
```

You do not need to wrap it in another observer.

Comment: Any suggestions with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301712/shiny-observeevent-and-actionbutton-adding-a-column-to-table